# What happens in Future.pipeTo within actor

Tags: scala, akka

I have a call to 3rd party library(which returs a future) within my actor receive. I am piping that future to Self, so that I can process the reply as a messsage in the mailbox.

```
class MyActor{
  def receive:Receive = {
    case x:Message => {
      val future = callToThridPartyLib(x)
      future pipeTo self
    }
    case x:Reply => {
      //process reply received on future completion
    }
  }
}
```

My questions are

1. What is the overhead of this approach?
2. Will there be a separate thread allocated for each such pipeTo
   statement?
3. If so, should there be a Thread pool to manage pipeTo to avoid all
   threads getting used up?

Thank you

Comment: ^^ If I were you I'd have a look at the code: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/pattern/PipeToSupport.scala

Comment: Thanks Viktor, I had seen the code but still had the doubt on the overhead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What Victor says, but essentially:
The overhead of `pipeTo` is very low: it creates one closure, which sends one message. That's it, no additional threading involved. The message is being sent from the thread on which the `Future` has been completed, and will be received, like all the actor messages, on the dispatcher that has been configured for the given actor.

You should take care of `ExecutionContext` for that `callToThirdPartyLib` though. If it uses blocking calls inside, and you use default Akka dispatcher to run it (what your code suggests), you might run out of threads quickly. However, this seems to be off-topic for the question.

Comment: The pipeTo uses andThen, and the akka documentation for andThen says - "andThen creates a new Future with the specified callback, a Future that will have the same result as the Future it’s called on, which allows for ordering like in the following sample:". So a new Future is created, will it use the same thread as its parent's ?

Comment: When completed it will schedule a task using the implicit `ExecutorContext`. That's what determines which concrete thread to run on.